# jqGrid : is it possible to group a multi-value field?

Tags: jqgrid, grouping

Is this possible with jqGrid ?

- rowItem 1,fieldVal : "ValueA", ...
- rowItem 2,fieldVal : "ValueA ValueB", ...
- rowItem 3,fieldVal : "ValueA ValueC", ...
- rowItem 4,fieldVal : "ValueC ValueB", ...

(separator is space for fieldVal)

Try to have a unique single group column with each category as one field value like this :

`+ ValueA

   rowItem1

   rowItem2

   rowItem3

+ ValueB

   rowItem2

   rowItem4

+ ValueC

   rowItem3

   rowItem4`